# Add Google Firebase Admob to iOS project with Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, firebase, admob, swift-package-manager, firebase-admob

How can I add Google admob to my iOS project via Swift Package manager? I could only find a way to add it via Cocoa-pods.

Comment: I created a repository is alternate for using that as Swift package manager.  

Link here: https://github.com/quanghits/GoogleMobileAds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems as if there are no possible ways to install via SPM at the moment. Here is a [Github](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/1125) discussion explaining some of the technical details.

Comment: I created a repository is alternate for using that as Swift package manager. Link here: https://github.com/quanghits/GoogleMobileAds